# Extract object keys by type of the property

Tags: typescript

I have this object and I want to extract the keys `"a" | "b"`, because the properties are not primitive and I then also want to extract `"c"`, because its type is a primitive.

```
interface Obj {
  a: { // let's call this object simply A
    x: string
    y: {
      z: string
    }
  }
  b: { // let's call this object simply B
    u: boolean
  }
  c: number
}
```

How can I achieve it?

I tried these steps:

```
type AnyObject = Record<string, any>

type Keys = string & keyof Obj // "a" | "b" | "c"

type T01 = Obj[Keys] // number | A | B 

type T02 = Extract<T01, AnyObject> // A | B
type T03 = Exclude<T01, AnyObject> // number
```

I then tried to tweak the `Extract` and `Exclude` types, but it gives me back all original keys `"a" | "b" | "c"`.

```
/**
 * Exclude from T those types that are assignable to U
 */
type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;

type Leaf<K extends keyof Obj = string & Keys, T = Obj[K]> = T extends AnyObject ? never : K
type T04 = Leaf // "a" | "b" | "c"
```

Both branches of the conditional type return all keys.

And this one doesn't do anything at all.

```
type Leaf<K extends keyof Obj = string & Keys> = Obj[K] extends AnyObject ? K : never
type T04 = Leaf // never
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional mapped type to extract just the keys that match the given condition

```
interface Obj {
  a: { // let's call this object simply A
    x: string
    y: {
      z: string
    }
  }
  b: { // let's call this object simply B
    u: boolean
  }
  c: number
}

type JustPrimitives<O extends Record<PropertyKey, any>> = {
    [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends object ? never : K
}[keyof O]
type JustNonPrimitives<O extends Record<PropertyKey, any>> = {
    [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends object ? K : never
}[keyof O]

type P = JustPrimitives<Obj> // "c"
type NP = JustNonPrimitives<Obj> // "a" | "b"
```

Comment: Amazing. I was so focused on the previous solution that I totally missed mapped types. Thank you.